# Any .NET implementation of Concise Binary Object Representation(CBOR)?

Tags: .net, binary-data, data-transfer, data-exchange, cbor

I'm on the look-out for any implementations of [this new binary data representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049).

Comment: Google search for "cbor implementation c#" provides [this](https://github.com/peteroupc/CBOR) lucky hit :-)

Comment: New C# implementation: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Cbor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the .Net 5.0 Extension provided by MS

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Formats.Cbor/5.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.cbor

https://github.com/dotnet/performance/search?q=cbor

Here you have an sample to write and read:

```
using System;
using System.Formats.Cbor;

var writer = new CborWriter();
        
writer.WriteStartArray(3);
writer.WriteInt64(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
writer.WriteInt32(1);
writer.WriteStartArray(1);
writer.WriteInt32(9);
writer.WriteEndArray();
writer.WriteEndArray();
        
var myByteArray = writer.Encode();
    
    
var reader = new CborReader(data);
    
reader.ReadStartArray();
long unixDT = reader.ReadInt64();
int myInt = reader.ReadInt32();
reader.ReadStartArray();
int myInt2 = reader.ReadInt32();
reader.ReadEndArray();
reader.ReadEndArray();
    
var response = new object[]
    {
        unixDT,
        myInt,
        new object[] { myInt2 }
    };
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

A list of several CBOR implementations can be found at http://cbor.io — this includes a C# implementation.

Answer (score 2):

## Dahomey.Cbor

High-performance CBOR serialization framework for .Net

### Features

- Serialization/Deserialization from/to Streams, byte buffer
- Object Model
- Mapping to any .Net class
- Extensible Polymorphism support based on discriminator conventions
- Extensible Naming conventions
- Custom converters for not supported types
- [.Net standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md) support

https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Cbor

Answer (score 2):

As an alternitive you can look at the Nuget-Package

[PeterO.Cbor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterO.Cbor) (source: https://github.com/peteroupc/CBOR).

looks (at the moment of writing) maintained and has a lot stars.